# Add row to tbody with class or id not with tagname

Tags: jquery

I try to add a new rows to table in tbody tag when i user jQuery append function i works when the selector is `$('tbody')` but when it's `$('tbody.layout_1')` for example it doesn't work, what is the difference ?!

Comment: Does your `tbody` have a class of layout_1? Also, post your HTML.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between the selector `tbody` and the selector `tbody.layout_1`?

Comment: Yes it have, no i don't ask about the difference

Comment: If you're not asking the difference between the two, I'd suggest re-wording your question to ask the question you want answered; and as everyone else has indicated, no one can help you fix the problem without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

`$('tbody')` selects `tbody` tag element

`$('tbody.layout_1')` selects `tbody` tag element with class `layout_1`

Example

```
<tbody class="layout_1">
```

Comment: I know and the tbody has a class "layout_1" but append not working in the second case selection

Comment: You would need to show your code since that should definitely work. I'm guessing a typo somewhere.